# Internal Tracing of Redis,Mongo or Outbound Http call are not showing in kibana

Tags: go, elastic-stack, elk, apm, go-gin

I have implemented a small poc code for measuring average time taken for each request. In the code my intension is to call **mongo**,**redis** and other external service calls from my code.The code I have implemented is in go and I am using go gin-**gonic** library and I implemented **APM** middleware in it.I have also done whole **elk setup** in my local through **docker-compose** and in that **elasticsearch**,**APM**,**kibana** containers are all working fine and they are able to show the dashboard for my calls but the problem I am facing is that I am not getting their internal distributed traces of the call in its **apm** **kibana** dashboard i.e.(how much each get or set inside the **Redis** is taking time or **mongo** insert is taking time or my outbound service call is taking time) .So somebody can please tell me where I am doing wrong or what I am missing in the code.

I have followed this documentation as my reference:

[Instrumentation Module For Setting up Apm agent with go](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/go/master/builtin-modules.html#builtin-modules-apmrestful)

I want a dashboard like this

[Distributed Tracing of Log Example Pic of Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwaEN.png)

but I am getting only this much

[This kind of tracing is what I am getting in each call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohtLe.png)

Here is my Docker-Compose.yml

````
version: '3.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9201
    networks:
      - elastic

  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9202:9202
    networks:
      - elastic

  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
    container_name: kib01
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  apm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: apm.docker
    container_name: apm
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local


networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
    ```
````

here is my apm.docker file

```
COPY apm-server.yml /usr/share/apm-server/apm-server.yml
USER root
RUN chown root:apm-server /usr/share/apm-server/apm-server.yml
USER apm-server
```

here is my gin_poc_client.go file

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
    "go.elastic.co/apm"
    "go.elastic.co/apm/module/apmgin"
    "go.elastic.co/apm/module/apmhttp"
    "go.elastic.co/apm/module/apmmongo"
    "go.elastic.co/apm/module/apmredigo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)


func main() {



    r := gin.New()
    r.Use(apmgin.Middleware(r))
    gin.SetMode(gin.DebugMode)

    redisPool:=&redis.Pool{
        // Maximum number of idle connections in the pool.
        MaxIdle: 80,
        // max number of connections
        MaxActive: 12000,
        // Dial is an application supplied function for creating and
        // configuring a connection.
        Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
            c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "localhost:6379")
            if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            return c, err
        },
    }


    r.GET("/redis/set", func(c *gin.Context) {
        conn := apmredigo.Wrap(redisPool.Get()).WithContext(c)
        defer conn.Close()
        //err := client.Set("Hey", "hey100", 0).Err()
        _, err := conn.Do("SET", "hey5","hey500")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"Hey": "hey100"})
    })

    r.GET("/redis/get", func(c *gin.Context) {
        conn := apmredigo.Wrap(redisPool.Get()).WithContext(c)
        defer conn.Close()
        val, err := conn.Do("GET", "hey5")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("key", val)

        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"get": val})
    })


    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.GET("/hello/supratim", func(c *gin.Context) {
        span, ctx := apm.StartSpan(c, "main", "custom")
        fmt.Println("Starting APM Spanning")
        defer span.End()
        request,err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8001/hello/supratim", nil)
        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Println("ERROR IS",err)
        }


        client := apmhttp.WrapClient(http.DefaultClient)
        fmt.Println("Wrapping APM Http",client)
        result, err1 := client.Do(request.WithContext(ctx))
        if err1!=nil{
            fmt.Println("ERROR in client request",err1)
        }
        body,err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(result.Body)
        if err2 !=nil{
            fmt.Println("ERROR IN BODY",err2)
        }
        fmt.Println("result ", string(body))

        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": string(body),
        })


    })


    var mongoClient, _ = mongo.Connect(
        context.Background(),
        options.Client().SetMonitor(apmmongo.CommandMonitor()),
    )
    var collection *mongo.Collection
    r.GET("/mongo/ping",func(c *gin.Context) {
        collection = mongoClient.Database("dbAPM").Collection("poc")
        _, err := collection.Find(c, bson.D{})
        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Println("Error",err)
        }
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })

    r.GET("/mongo/insert",func(c *gin.Context) {
        collection = mongoClient.Database("dbAPM").Collection("poc")
        result, err := collection.InsertOne(c, bson.M{"foo": "bar1", "hello": "world1", "pi": 3.14159})
        fmt.Println("RESULT IS",result)
        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Println("Error",err)
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                "message": err,
            })
        }
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": result,
        })
    })
    r.Run(":8000")

}
```

here is my gin_poc_server.go file for outbound call from gin_poc_client file

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "go.elastic.co/apm/module/apmgorilla"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!\n", mux.Vars(req)["name"])
}
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Use(apmgorilla.Middleware())
    r.HandleFunc("/hello/{name}", helloHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8001", r))
}
```